# Create certificate let's encrypt with iis

Tags: iis, lets-encrypt, windows-server-2012-r2

in windows server 2012, I installed `IIS`.
I created a site with host name `host1` (name of windows server) and create a folder called host1 under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, contains a html file.

when navigate http://host1/, I got the desired content of the html file

Now, I have to create a certificate using [that thread](https://miketabor.com/how-to-install-a-lets-encrypt-ssl-cert-on-microsoft-iis/).

I success all the steps, but stucked on step 7:

[image: is]

at that step, the cmd of (wacs.exe) is closed by it self.

Could you please help me solving that issue ? Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the reason behind the issue you need to check the event viewer log.

I tried to reproduce your issue. I got the below error in event viewer:

> A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013.

[image]

you will find this log under the windows-> system logs.

The reason behind the issue is on your machine TLS 1.2 is not enabled.

To resolve the issue you could follow the below steps:

1)open the registry editor.

2) go to the below section:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2

set below value to the particular section:

client:

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

"Enabled"=dword:00000001

Server:

"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[image]

[image]

**Note: Do not forget to restart your machine after editing registry key values.**

reference link:

[A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121859/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-a-tls-client-credential-the-internal-erro)