# BizTalk's 2016 Office 365 Adapter ReceiveLocation periodically shuts down

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

My Office365 Adapter sometimes shutdown; the only thing I can find is these messages in the EventLog, which are rather vague:

> 11:26:28 am - The receive location
> "Office365.PublishEmail.ReceiveLocation.IntegrationEmail" with URL
> "O365Mail://email@mycompany.com/Inbox" is shutting down. Details:"The
> error threshold was exceeded. ".
>
> 11:25:28 The adapter "Office365 Outlook Email" raised an error
> message. Details "The Event Log Error Threshold was reached. The
> adapter will continue polling, but further event log entries will be
> suppressed. ".
>
> 11:25:28 The adapter "Office365 Outlook Email" raised an error
> message. Details "An error occurred while sending the request."
>
> 11:22:43 Info Msg - from "BizTalkTMS": Service Heartbeat

So today, I enabled it, it got the emails that were queued up (so no security issues), and then it went through the same shutdown steps again.  I noticed last time, the same thing happened, after getting about 7 or 8 emails after being enabled (I can see traces of our orchestrations that run upon receiving an email).

Today, I re-enabled the ReceiveLocation at 2:07 pm, and this time, no queue up emails were waiting. It disabled itself again with the same sequence of messages/errors starting at 2:17 pm.  It disabled itself again at 3:00 pm.

Then I went to check the "Configure" button on that receive location, and now getting this message (first time I've seen it):
[image]

I have an idea on the above.  We had the systems team apply registry changes to force all apps to use TLS 1.2. (See here: [BizTalk 2016 Office 365 Adapter and TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73336434/biztalk-2016-office-365-adapter-and-tls-1-2))

Above is in our QA environment.  The "configure" button opens the next screen okay in our DEV environment.  I'm restarted the same ReceiveLocation in DEV, and it is also get the warnings and presumable will shut down in a few minutes.

The "BizTalk TMS service" is running and writing heartbeat messages to the EventLog periodically.

When we first installed the BizTalk application with that receive location, it worked fine for at least several weeks.

If it just happened periodically, it might make sense if Office 365 has a short outage.  But the fact that I restarted it, and it disabled itself again within an hour shows something else is probably wrong.

I'm probably going to create some type of alert/email for this, but would like any ideas if other people experience this and what exactly causes it.

Updated: 09/12/2022

In the **System** Event Log, when I enable the Receive Location, I see a multiple of these messages:

> A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The
> internal error state is 10013.

They seem to stop when the Receive Location disables itself.

There are a few sites I'm reading about this, one of them is here: [A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121859/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-a-tls-client-credential-the-internal-erro)

Comment: Do you have any custom behaviors on any other send port on the same host instance that is setting any SSL settings?  If so you might want to run them on separate host instances.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - No, we had to create a separate Host and Host Instance for this receive, because it requires SSO access above and beyond what the other hosts needed.  So this ReceiveLocation is the only things running in this Host Instance.

Comment: Added update about System EventLog messages (following "Updated: 09/12/2022").

Comment: Hmm, strange, according to this blog (non BizTalk) it means it tried to use TLS 1.0/1.1   https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-a-tls-client-credential#:~:text=The%20internal%20error%20state%20is,for%20connecting%20to%20the%20internet.   Did you actually disable those?